# UWP DataGrid wont update the UI when the Item Source was changed in c#

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, uwp, datagrid, uwp-xaml

Hi on my UWP app i use a `DataGrid` control (microsoft community nuget) it updates on load but when added new items it wont get update the UI. when at start the app trigger and load from the data source but after added new items it wont get refreshed even tho the `ObservableCollection` get changed. data add through a `ContentDialog`, does `ContentDialog` block call to the frame when get called ?

```
        <controls:DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Collection,Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White"


             Grid.Row="1"
             Margin="12"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
             AlternatingRowForeground="Gray"
             AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"                     
             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
             CanUserSortColumns="False"
             CanUserResizeColumns="False"
             CanUserReorderColumns="True"
             ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
             MaxColumnWidth="400"
             IsReadOnly="False"

             RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
             SelectionMode="Extended">
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn
            x:Name="id"
        Header="ID" 
        Width="SizeToHeader"
        Binding="{Binding ID,Mode=OneWay}" 
        FontSize="20"
                Visibility="Visible">
                <controls:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    </Style>
                </controls:DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </controls:DataGridTextColumn>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="ID" 
        Width="SizeToHeader"
        Binding="{Binding Number,Mode=OneWay}" 
                Tag="ID"
        FontSize="20" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="ID" 
        Width="SizeToHeader"
        Binding="{Binding Name,Mode=OneWay}" 
        FontSize="20" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="ID" 
        Width="SizeToHeader"
        Binding="{Binding StartDate,Mode=OneWay}" 
        FontSize="20" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="ID" 
        Width="SizeToHeader"
        Binding="{Binding EndDate,Mode=OneWay}" 
        FontSize="20" />
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

**Here is my viewmodel**

```
class PermitsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //public  List<PermitData> PermitsData { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<PermitData> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return Collection;
        }
        set
        {
            Collection = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Collection"));
            }
        }
    }
    private static Frame _EntryFrame;


    public PermitsViewModel() {
        //PermitsData = new List<PermitData> {
        //new PermitData { ID = 9966615, Number = 78, Name = "Mark",  StartDate = new DateTime(2016, 8, 30), EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 30) },
        //new PermitData { ID = 9945512, Number = 79, Name = "Steve", StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 7, 30), EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 9, 30) }
        //};
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<PermitData>();
        Collection.Add(new PermitData { ID = 22, Number = 22, Name = "KASUN", StartDate = new DateTime(2016, 8, 30), EndDate = new DateTime(2016, 8, 30) });
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }

     public void AddToTable(int ID, int Number, string Name, DateTime StDate, DateTime EndDate)
    {

        //Collection = new ObservableCollection<PermitData>();
        Collection.Add(new PermitData { ID = ID, Number = Number, Name = Name, StartDate = new DateTime(2016, 8, 30), EndDate = new DateTime(2016, 8, 30) });
        Debug.WriteLine(Collection[0]);

        //OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**Data property layer**

```
class PermitData
{
    public  int ID { get; set; }
    public  int Number { get; set; }
    public  string Name { get; set; }
    public  DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public  DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

**main**

```
public sealed partial class Permits : Page
{
    PermitsViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new PermitsViewModel();
    public Permits()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel.Init(DataEntryPort);
        base.DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when you added new item in ViewModel.Collection through a ContentDialog, the UI didn't display the new data? I used your code and tried to add new items, it worked, so can you provide more information about how you added it or provide a simple sample that can be reproduced? In addition, what does "does ContentDialog block call to the frame when get called?"  mean?

Comment: the gridview frame load inside another frame was that be the problem or conntentDialog freeze the frame behind when poped up ?

Comment: i added through a button in the mainframe which load the datagrid inside the mainframe using a child frame and popup a contentdialog  to add data

Comment: By my testing, the contentDialog didn't block the frame and the dataGrid can update after adding the new data. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us?